# Maximum independent set in a hypergraph

Tags: algorithms

The problem is this,
say you have a set $E$ of elements $e$, and you have a list of elements you want to remove from this set. But for an element to be removed, one of its dependencies must stay in the set. The list of elements to remove is as follows:

$e_1$  : $a, b, c, d$ ...
$e_2$  : $e, f, g, h$ ...
...

So in order to remove $e$, one of the elements "$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$...." must remain.
The question is how to remove the maximum number of elements while keeping one of its dependencies.

Note that all elements are in the same set, so a dependency of one element can be in the list of elements to remove.
Also if it helps, there is an upper bound on the number of dependencies for an element.

Comment: Can you formulate this problem as maximum independent set in a hypergraph?

Comment: Could you explain a little how is this problem related to hypergraphs?

Comment: The constraints state that you cannot remove a vertex along with all of its dependees.